# 8K HDMI display support orange pi 5

Tags: display, display-resolution, hdmi

I have tried to connect 8K Display to orange pi 5 through hdmi but it shows 4K resolution. Is there anyone who tested 8K HDMI connection?
I am using Orangepi5_1.1.6_ubuntu_focal_desktop_xfce_linux5.10.110.
I also created a virtual display but it fails to create 8K 60Hz display or 4K 120Hz. When I create them using cvt and xrandr commands it hangs and stops working. But created 4K at 60Hz.